# docent display pop up with table id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I click on my button "Select" it should show me the HTML popup, and for some reason is not happening.

Could it be some id problem or hard code?

The main idea is to click and bring some kind of list reading from a random array list.

Below: my .js with the call back id and display.

Any ideas?

```
<!-- This hosts all HTML templates that will be used inside the JavaScript code -->
            <table class ="cls-{id} active-{active}" style="display: none;" width="100%" id="rowTemplate">
                    <tr class ="bb cls-{id} active-{active}">
                        <td class="active-{active}" id="{id}-question" width="70%">{question}</td>
                        <td class="cls-{id} active-{active}" width="30%">
                            <button class="buttons" step="0.01" data-clear-btn="false" style="background: #006b54; color:white !important ;" id="{id}-inspectionResult"></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>

                <div id="projectPopUp"  class="popup-window" style="display:none">
                    <div class="popuptitle" id="details-name"></div>
                        <table width="100%" id="detailsgrid">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Start Time</td>
                                <td> <select id="details-startTime" data-role="none"></select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">End Time</td>
                                <td> <select id="details-endTime" data-role="none"></select></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <div>
                        <button class="smallButton" onClick="closeProjectPopup()">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="smallButton" onClick="submitProjectPopup()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <table style="display: none;" id="sectionRowTemplate">
                <tr width="100%" class="bb cls-{id}-row2 sectionheader">
                    <td class="cls-{id}" colspan="3">{question}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Javascript code:

```
var buildQuestionnaire = function(){
    parseInitialDataHolder();

    for (var i = 0; i < ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS.length; i++){
        var id = i;
        var data = {
            id: id,
            question: ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].question,
            inspectionResult: '',
            active: true
        };
        var initialdata = initialdataholder[id];
        if(initialdata) {
            data = initialdata;
        }
        dataholder.push(data);

        if (typeof ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].header == 'undefined') {
            $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#rowTemplate tbody", data));
            $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text(data.inspectionResult || 'Select');
            $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").click(resultHandler.bind(data));
            updateActiveStatus(data);
            commentvisibilitymanager(data);
        }
        else {
            $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#sectionRowTemplate tbody", data));
        }
    }

}
//to show the popup
$('#projectPopUp').show();

//to close the popup
$('#projectPopUp').hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
    buildQuestionnaire();
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: only gives me projectPopUp error; I already try to call the ids and still not loading the pop up window